# What instead Jquery Mobile for Cordova project

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an cordova app with Jquery Mobile. It has 20+ page on one html file and this is so messy and starts laggin while page transitions. Can I remove this lagg? Or maybe do you guys know better solution then Jquery Mobile for cordova?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't answer this question. However, if you can do without Jquery you would remove a lot of overhead. Do you have images, and did you optimize them?

Comment: All of my images weight ~5mb. What do you mean 'optimize'? There is a quick solution to optimizei it? And I notice that if I open app and go to page1 its laggy, but when I go back and again go to page1 it is vere more smooth.

Comment: Programs like http://optimizilla.com/ will take your images and cut down the file size. 5MB for 1 page is a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Ionic framework : http://ionicframework.com/

It's the best framework to create hybrid mobile application with phonegap.